# Entity with @Column length greater than 255 characters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee

Since the default is 255 how would I specify an "infinite" length to hold information such as a huge text? It should not be a vendor specific solution such as the "columnDefinition" property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a "text" (lob)
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-character.html

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
```

Comment: Is there any implications?

Comment: Dépends of your version of hibernate. For 3 see this http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/299/string-lobs-on-postgresql-with-hibernate-36.html

Comment: `BLOB` is a binary large object and has nothing to do wit a "blog". It's also meant for *binary* data not for text, as the name implies.